# Getting http://127.0.0.1:8000/route('welcome') instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've come across a peculiar bug in a laravel project of mine,

In my web.php I have a named route 'welcome' :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');
```

This route contain my index page in which there's a navigation component.

Through an AppServiceProvider I'm passing data to the navigation component

The data im passing is a simple table containing this :

{
name : "home",

href : "route('welcome')"

}

```
<nav>

@foreach

<a href=" {{ myData->href }} "> {{ myData->name }} </a>

@endforeach

</nav>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link "home" it sends me to this address :

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/route('welcome')](http://127.0.0.1:8000/route(%27welcome%27))
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaET1.png

Instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/

and this is a problem with every single link, it always returns

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/route('myLink')](http://127.0.0.1:8000/route(%27myLink%27))

this is my complete web.php for further information

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('welcome');

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::resource('/nav', NavController::class);




// // Fallback page error 404

Route::fallback(FallbackController::class);
```

If you need more information please ask me, i've been trying to fix this issue for 2 days, and it is frustrating me.

I tried route:clear, cache:clear, view:clear and nothing changes.

Is it the format at which I've stored the name of the route that isn't working ?

The thing is it was working for an hour or two. and now impossible to fix it.

I hope someone here can help.

Josh's solution is working.

The route('welcome') was passed through as a string.  and the function route() was not called.

Comment: The error most likely is in the way you are passing the data to the view. It seems the literal ```"route('welcome')"```  its being passed instead of the actual result of the helper. Could you paste the relevant code of your ```AppServiceProvider```?

Comment: Thank you @KennyHorna exactly what was received was the string "route('welcome') and the function route() was not called, Josh's solution "below your comment" gave me the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, for the key `href` you just need to store `welcome` instead of `route('welcome')`. Then in your blade template, you can do

```
<a href="{{ route(myData->href) }}">login here</a>
```

The reason your solution is not working is that you just have the word `route` stored as a string, you aren't actually calling the function called `route`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I knew I might have done something wrong.

I don't think I would have figured it out on my own because I had tried :

`<a href=" {{  route( {{  myData->href }} )  }} "> my Link </a>` and it was throwing an error !